# What's wrong with my list item template here?

Tags: sapui5, sap-fiori

If Begda is set, I want to display " - ", otherwise just "". When Begda is set the output shows "NaN", otherwise it shows the type correctly. So the ternary operator works, but the formatter doesn't work. The Begda field contains actual date objects:

```
this._oSelectedTrainingsModel.getData()[0].Begda
15:31:37.916 Date 2016-09-17T00:00:00.000Z

var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
                title: "{Title}",
                description: "{= ${Begda} ? ${Type} - ${ path: 'Begda', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'medium' }} : ${Type} }",
                icon: "{icon}",
                iconInset: false
            });
```

I also tried this with the same 'NaN' output:

```
var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            title: "{Title}",
            description: "{= ${Begda} ? ${Type} - ${Begda}.toLocaleDateString() : ${Type} }",
            icon: "{icon}",
            iconInset: false
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the framework tries to apply a subtraction on the given values. If you want to include the - character in your expression, do like a string concatenation `+ '-' +`.

It's also recommended to put complex calcuations into brackets.
Here is the fixed code (brackets are optional):

```
var oItemTemplate = new sap.m.StandardListItem({
            title: "{Title}",
            description: "{= ${Begda} ? (${Type} + '-' + ${ path: 'Begda', type: 'sap.ui.model.type.Date', formatOptions: { style: 'medium' }}) : ${Type} }",
            icon: "{icon}",
            iconInset: false
        });
```

Note that expression binding should be used only for simple logic, and this one seems to be a more complex which may be moved into a formatter function.